# Suppose i have an HTML table. How do I use JQuery events on this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
    <tr class="myRow"><td class="col1"></td><td class="col2"></td></tr>
    <tr class="myRow"><td class="col1"></td><td class="col2"></td></tr>
    <tr class="myRow"><td class="col1"></td><td class="col2"></td></tr>
    <tr class="myRow"><td class="col1"></td><td class="col2"></td></tr>
    <tr class="myRow"><td class="col1"></td><td class="col2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

How do I make the appropriate `col1` fill with the letters "ABC" when the user rollovers the row?

And then disappear the "ABC" when the user moves the mouse away from that row?

So far, I got this.
I solved it.

```
  $(".ep").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('td.playButtonCol').html('PLAY');
    },function(){
        $(this).find('td.playButtonCol').html('');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

```
$('.col1').mouseenter(function(){ ... });
$('.col1').mouseleave(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(".col1").hover(
function(){
 $(this).html = ('abc');
    )};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague but if I understand you correctly you want to hover over a row and put a value in one particular cell in that row. If so, that's relatively easy:

```
$("tr").hover(function() {
  $(this).children(".col1").html("ABC");
}, function() {
  $(this).children(".col1").html("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you means something like this?:

```
$('.col1').hover(function() {
    $(this).html('ABC');
}, function() {
    $(this).html('');
});
```